# EF Error: "The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts."

Tags: entity-framework, join, datacontext

I've gone through several other threads which were raised about the same error, but didn't get a solution:

```
        public IQueryable GetHolidays(IQueryable<Location> locations, Location currentLocation)
    {
        int currentLocationType = currentLocation.FkLocationTypeId;

        var holidays = ClientContext.Holidays;

        //get all holidays for the given locations
        var holidaysPerLocation = (
                                    //get permissions added in their own level
                                    from h in holidays
                                    where (from l in locations where l.FkLocationTypeId >= currentLocationType select l.LocationId).Contains(h.FkLocationId)
                                     && h.FkHolidayParentId == null
                                    select h)
                                    .Union
                                  ( 
                                    //get permissions overriden at the current level 
                                    from h in holidays
                                    where (from l in locations where l.FkLocationTypeId >= currentLocationType select l.LocationId).Contains(h.FkLocationId)
                                        && h.FkHolidayParentId != null && h.InheritedStatus == "U"
                                    select h).Union
                                  (
                                    //get holidays from parent levels which are opted in
                                    from h in holidays
                                    join h1 in holidays on h.HolidayId equals h1.FkHolidayParentId 
                                    where (from l in locations where l.FkLocationTypeId < currentLocationType select l.LocationId).Contains(h.FkLocationId)
                                        && h.InheritedStatus == "I"
                                    select h);

        return holidaysPerLocation;
    }
```

ERROR: "The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts."

Originally I tried to directly query ClientContext.Holidays in my LINQ query, instead of separately taking it in to the memory, but that too gave me the same error. Now as far as I can see, I'm not referencing two data contexts, and I'm not sure why I get this error.

Comment: `currentLocation` was retrieved from another context than `location` points to. Look for places where you dispose your context.

Comment: I didn't quite get you. currentLocation and locations list are two objects passed from elsewhere. Can't I use that in the LINQ query then?